Composable card with elevation is not rounded with the shadow
I am using a Card with an elevation for the shadow, But the shadow doesn't have round corners. Is there way to have a card elevation to have rounded corners.
This is my code my code
@Composable
fun HotelImageCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(bottom = 22.dp)) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth().clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.hotelimage2),
                contentDescription = null
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter).background(color = Color.Blue)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color.White,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                text = "Top 11 Gourmet/Cuisine hotels in Bali"
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
                color = Color.White,
                text = "1/5"
            )
        }

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .offset(y = 26.dp),
            color = Color.Gray,
            fontSize = 10.sp,
            text = "Sponsored"
        )

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .offset(y = 20.dp)
                .padding(end = 16.dp),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 8.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 4.dp, start = 16.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
            ) {
                Text(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    text = "$ 61,569"
                )

                Text(
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    fontSize = 10.sp,
                    text = "1 night with taxes"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

As you can see in the red box the card displaying the price is not rounded perfectly.


By default, Card uses RoundedCornerShape(12.dp) shape, which gives it those rounded corners you’re seeing. Same shape also applies to the shadow when you set an elevation, so the shadow itself is already rounded by 12.dp.
If the shadow isn’t fully visible, it’s because there isn’t enough space for it to be drawn. The parent Box has a bottom padding of 22.dp, and the Card is offset by 20.dp on the Y-axis, leaving only 2.dp at the bottom for the shadow, which isn’t enough for the 8.dp elevation.
To fix this, just increase the bottom padding of the parent Box so the shadow has enough room to show. Here’s the updated code.
@Composable
fun HotelImageCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(bottom = 30.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(250.dp)
                    .background(Color.Gray)
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                    .background(color = Color.Blue)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color.White,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                text = "Top 11 Gourmet/Cuisine hotels in Bali"
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
                color = Color.White,
                text = "1/5"
            )
        }

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .offset(y = 26.dp),
            color = Color.Gray,
            fontSize = 10.sp,
            text = "Sponsored"
        )

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .offset(y = 20.dp)
                .padding(end = 16.dp),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 8.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 4.dp, start = 16.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
            ) {
                Text(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    text = "$ 61,569"
                )

                Text(
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    fontSize = 10.sp,
                    text = "1 night with taxes"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


Here's the card with a red shadow for better visibility, making the rounded shadow stand out clearly. I used the RoundedCornerShape(12.dp) for the shadow since it matches the shape applied to the Card for clipping by default. The code below is just for validation, so feel free to ignore it. I'm using graphicsLayer for the shadow, as this is what Card uses internally to render the shadow.
@Composable
fun HotelImageCard(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(bottom = 30.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(250.dp)
                    .background(Color.Gray)
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                    .background(color = Color.Blue)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                color = Color.White,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                text = "Top 11 Gourmet/Cuisine hotels in Bali"
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
                color = Color.White,
                text = "1/5"
            )
        }

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .offset(y = 26.dp),
            color = Color.Gray,
            fontSize = 10.sp,
            text = "Sponsored"
        )

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .offset(y = 20.dp)
                .padding(end = 16.dp)
                .graphicsLayer{
                    shadowElevation = 8.dp.toPx()
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)
                    clip = false
                    spotShadowColor = Color.Red
                },
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
//            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 8.dp),
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 8.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 4.dp, start = 16.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
            ) {
                Text(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    text = "$ 61,569"
                )

                Text(
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    fontSize = 10.sp,
                    text = "1 night with taxes"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}



thanks, it was the bottom padding on the outer box that needed to be increased.

if ur wondering how to make shadows rounded, modify the Card() to have shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp).

There's nothing wrong with the code you provided, and you can't always fix the shadow in these cases by adding padding, because you may have strict requirements.
In this particular case, it looks like the shadow is being clipped by the container. I often see this behavior when LazyColumn wraps the content size instead, because it's clipping it.
If this is the case, you need to make sure your lazy container is taking all the space it's expected to use when it's full. In a basic scenario it's just Modifier.fillMaxSize():
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    items(1) {
        HotelImageCard()
    }
}

